# How to route audio to default speakers in Swift for macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a function playing audio for a macOS swiftUI app but I want it to play the sound through the default built in speakers every single time. Does anyone know of any reliable method for this?

I've researched a lot but haven't found a solid method for macos. This is what I've tried:

1. AVRoutePickerView

This was only availble for ios and Mac catalyst but not macOS

2. Getting Device ID in AVAudioEngine

I found this code snippet but it assumes that the built in speaker device ID stays the same which it doesnt so that doesn't help.

```
    engine = AVAudioEngine()
    let output = engine.outputNode

    // get the low level input audio unit from the engine:
    let outputUnit = output.audioUnit!
    // use core audio low level call to set the input device:
    var outputDeviceID: AudioDeviceID = 51  // replace with actual, dynamic value
    AudioUnitSetProperty(outputUnit,
                         kAudioOutputUnitProperty_CurrentDevice,
                         kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                         0,
                         &outputDeviceID,
                         UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioDeviceID>.size))
```

3. Disabling bluetooth so the audio only goes through main speakers and not bluetooth speaker. This didn't seem the best approach so I havent' tested it.

The following is the code I have for playing sound:

```
func playTheSound() {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Blow", withExtension: "mp3")
    player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
    player?.play()
    print("Sound was played")
    //
```

So, any recommendations on how to route the audio to main speakers for macOS?

Answer (score 1):

By "default built-in" I assume you actually just mean "built-in." The default speakers are the ones the audio will route to already.

The simplest solution to this that will *probably* always work is to route to the UID "BuiltInSpeakerDevice". For example, this does what you want:

```
let player = AVPlayer()

func playTheSound() {
    let url = URL(filePath: "/System/Library/Sounds/Blow.aiff")
    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
    player.audioOutputDeviceUniqueID = "BuiltInSpeakerDevice"
    player.play()
}
```

Note the use of AVPlayer and `audioOutputDeviceUniqueID` here. I'm betting this will work in approximately 100% of cases. It should even "work" if there were no built-in speakers, in that this silently fails (without crashing) if the UID doesn't exist.

But...sigh...I can't find anywhere that this is documented or any system constant for this string. And I really hate magic, undocumented strings. So, let's do it right. Besides, if we do it right, it'll work with AVAudioEngine, too. So let's get there.

First, you should always take a look at the invaluable  [CoreAudio output device useful methods in Swift 4](https://gist.github.com/rlxone/584467a63ac0ddf4d62fe1a983b42d0e). I don't know if anyone has turned this into a real framework, but this is a treasure trove of examples. The following code is a modernized version of that.

```
struct AudioDevice {
    let id: AudioDeviceID
    
    static func getAll() -> [AudioDevice] {
        var propertyAddress = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
            mSelector: kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices,
            mScope: kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
            mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMain)

        // Get size of buffer for list
        var devicesBufferSize: UInt32 = 0
        AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(AudioObjectID(kAudioObjectSystemObject), &propertyAddress,
                                       0, nil,
                                       &devicesBufferSize)
        let devicesCount = Int(devicesBufferSize) / MemoryLayout<AudioDeviceID>.stride

        // Get list
        let devices = Array<AudioDeviceID>(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: devicesCount) { buffer, initializedCount in
            AudioObjectGetPropertyData(AudioObjectID(kAudioObjectSystemObject), &propertyAddress,
                                       0, nil,
                                       &devicesBufferSize, buffer.baseAddress!)
            initializedCount = devicesCount
        }

        return devices.map(Self.init)
    }

    var hasOutputStreams: Bool {
        var propertySize: UInt32 = 256

        var propertyAddress = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
            mSelector: kAudioDevicePropertyStreams,
            mScope: kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
            mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMain)

        AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(id, &propertyAddress, 0, nil, &propertySize)

        return propertySize > 0
    }

    var isBuiltIn: Bool {
        transportType == kAudioDeviceTransportTypeBuiltIn
    }

    var transportType: AudioDevicePropertyID {
        var deviceTransportType = AudioDevicePropertyID()
        var propertySize = UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioDevicePropertyID>.size)

        var propertyAddress = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
            mSelector: kAudioDevicePropertyTransportType,
            mScope: kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
            mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMain)

        AudioObjectGetPropertyData(id, &propertyAddress,
                                   0, nil, &propertySize,
                                   &deviceTransportType)
        return deviceTransportType
    }

    var uid: String {
        var propertySize = UInt32(MemoryLayout<CFString>.size)

        var propertyAddress = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
            mSelector: kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceUID,
            mScope: kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
            mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMain)

        var result: CFString = "" as CFString
        AudioObjectGetPropertyData(id, &propertyAddress, 0, nil, &propertySize, &result)
        return result as String
    }
}
```

And with that in place, you can fetch the first built-in output device:

```
player.audioOutputDeviceUniqueID = AudioDevice.getAll()
        .first(where: {$0.hasOutputStreams && $0.isBuiltIn })?
        .uid
```

Or you can use your AVAudioEngine approach if you want more control (note difference between `uid` and `id` here):

```
let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
let engine = AVAudioEngine()

func playTheSound() {
    let output = engine.outputNode

    let outputUnit = output.audioUnit!
    var outputDeviceID = AudioDevice.getAll()
        .first(where: {$0.hasOutputStreams && $0.isBuiltIn })!
        .id

    AudioUnitSetProperty(outputUnit,
                         kAudioOutputUnitProperty_CurrentDevice,
                         kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                         0,
                         &outputDeviceID,
                         UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioDeviceID>.size))

    engine.attach(player)
    engine.connect(player, to: engine.outputNode, format: nil)
    try! engine.start()

    let url = URL(filePath: "/System/Library/Sounds/Blow.aiff")
    let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
    player.scheduleFile(file, at: nil)
    player.play()
}
```

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for the input. I just got around to getting back to this project and gave this a shot. For some reason this is what I'm getting in the console:

2023-01-22 17:07:55.496094-0700 builInSpekaers[12942:267042] AudioHardware-mac-imp.cpp:660    AudioObjectGetPropertyData: no object with given ID 0

Comment: First, of course: are there built-in speakers? But assuming yes, what is your list of outputs, and what *is* the uid of them (from the results of `getAll()`)?

Comment: Right, when I run getall() with my AirPods connected. I get the following two results:

[builInSpekaers.AudioDevice(id: 65), builInSpekaers.AudioDevice(id: 58)]

When I run it without my Airpods connected, I get the following: [builInSpekaers.AudioDevice(id: 58)]

Comment: However, how do I keep track of these on the user's computers where the ID's are prone to change?

Comment: So passing `"BuiltInSpeakerDevice"` fails though? Interesting. I wonder what's different there. In any case, the second example shows how to get the uid of the first builtin speaker (if any) directly. `AudioDevice.getAll().first(where: {$0.hasOutputStreams && $0.isBuiltIn })?.uid`

Comment: I figured it out. It was just the placement of the structs. I'll mark your answer correct but see the problem is: Let's say I don't have airpods connected. I run the program that plays the sound, and obviously it plays through the buildinspeakers. Now let's say I connect the airpods and I play the sound, the sound doesn't play through anything. 

In the other case however, when I have the airpods connected and then run the program to play the sound, it does play through builtinspeakers. So basically, the code runs fine as long as there are no 'switch' in audio outputs while it's running.

Comment: You probably aren't responding to audio route changes as required. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_route_changes

Comment: I figured that would be the case but I asked myself one question: let's say we're not responding to audio change. That means when AirPods are connected, the sound should keep playing through the built-in speakers right? But as I see, that's not the case. When AirPods are connected (while the program is running), the sound doesn't play at all. Should I still try to respond to audio route changes?

Comment: Yes. You should still respond the the audio route change. Depending on how things are configured and precisely which tools you're using, the player system may be pausing (it's unclear from your description whether the player is continuing or not). Look at the reason codes to see what's happening. You may also check the interruption notification and reason code (though I'm not certain those are sent on Mac).